# Is this syntax for an If Elif Else statement correct? There is an error for my variable name

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics

I am trying to set age and salary date into three categories and do no know what is messing up.

```
subset['AGE_Range'] = subset['AGE'].map(lambda x:'old' if x > 29 'mid' elif 25 < x < 30 else 'young')
subset['AVG_Salary_Range'] = subset['AVG_SALARY'].map(lambda x:'high' if x > 15000000 'med' elif 6000000 < x < 15000000 else 'low')
```

Here is the error that I receive.

```
File "/var/folders/hx/q1y8qq5n4fgc2fl8y1zfbhlw0000gn/T/ipykernel_15491/1445428960.py", line 1
    subset['AGE_Range'] = subset['AGE'].map(lambda x:'old' if x > 29 'mid' elif 25 < x < 30 else 'young')
                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

No, your `if` statement is not correct.  The inline `if` operator doesn't have an `elif` option.  So, don't use a lambda:

```
def agerange(x):
    if x > 29:
        return 'old'
    elif x > 25:
        return 'mid'
    else:
        return 'young'

def salaries(x):
    if x > 15000000:
        return 'high'
    elif x > 6000000:
        return 'med'
    else:
        return 'low'
...
subset['AGE_Range'] = subset['AGE'].map(agerange)
subset['AVG_Salary_Range'] = subset['AVG_SALARY'].map(salaries)
```

Comment: Thank you big homie it worked.